# jaspersoft studio change font color in crosstab

Tags: jasper-reports

I use jaspersoft studio and are creating a crosstab. How can I change the font color depending on value?.

> So when it is 0 i want it to be red, if its 1 then orange, above 2
>   green.

I have tried different examples but they refer to variables in normal reports. This how ever is in a crostab. and by adding hteir style sheets i keep getting java errors as the count value shown in a crostab is not a variable but a measure. 
"$V{COLUMN_5_MEASURE1}"

I am now stuck!!

**Current jrxml code**

here is the crosstab code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-01-14T10:33:46 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0eac5564-7241-4ddc-9c70-3dd9e65d8fcd">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter "/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Style1">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[<style name="ZFieldStyle">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{Z} < $F{Y}]]]]><![CDATA[></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#000000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{Z}>$F{X}]]]]><![CDATA[></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#FF0000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
...
<field name="X" class="java.lang.Integer"/>

...
<textField>
    <reportElement style="ZFieldStyle" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Z}]]]]><![CDATA[></textFieldExpression>
</textField>]]></conditionExpression>
            <style/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
    `accounts`.`name`
    , `accounts`.`id`
    ,users.`user_name`
    , DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)
    ,calls.`id`

FROM
    `d101`.`calls`
    INNER JOIN `d101`.`calls_contacts` 
        ON (`calls`.`id` = `calls_contacts`.`call_id`)
    INNER JOIN `d101`.`accounts_contacts` 
        ON (`calls_contacts`.`contact_id` = `accounts_contacts`.`contact_id`)
    INNER JOIN `d101`.`accounts` 
        ON (`accounts_contacts`.`account_id` = `accounts`.`id`)
        INNER JOIN users ON calls.`created_by` = users.`id`

        ;]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="user_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <field name="COLUMN_5" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="CustSaIndex" class="java.lang.String" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_5}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="CustSatIndex_Individual" class="java.lang.String" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_5}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="name">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="user_name">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{user_name}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="211" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="211" uuid="732a68fe-ddda-45e2-b3be-9dd21bd70ada">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <rowGroup name="user_name1" width="60" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{user_name}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="40" uuid="934d5cd7-7860-4413-8612-ae4147d9802e"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{user_name1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="3046862c-61c7-43d9-a379-d0afbed45073"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total user_name1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="name1" width="60" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="9b25a91d-34a1-49ab-bade-c0f09b58fc05"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{name1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="1939170d-5e2b-4e73-81c0-f2409ddd822d"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total name1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)1" height="20" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.sql.Date">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="050d35f6-e7a8-4108-925f-6957c5a5a17d"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0e258a6a-daff-4b4b-8c23-27b515b7cf15"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
```

***here is the field i need changed  on condition of field value count!***

```
                <measure name="COLUMN_5_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_5}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab_CG" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="d2eadf60-bf5e-46bd-a76c-09bdd755cca3"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="cf6c0dfc-b2b9-4590-bab2-3b83c619d243"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="user_name1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d8c569e9-790b-4f56-ae33-46a2f84eac08"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="user_name1" columnTotalGroup="DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="bc54fe2a-7b4b-419e-ba9d-6b4b084e45e9"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="name1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="d25d3d53-bba9-4af5-97d5-6f81e06249d8"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="name1" columnTotalGroup="DATE(`calls`.`date_entered`)1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="fd227041-65f9-4056-af4d-fdd8b150c190"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Thats normal fields, my question is withing a matrix? Crosstab?

Comment: And why do you think it's different?, have you tried the duplicated?, please  edit you question if you think it is different showing that the duplicated solution can not be used. I will be more then happy to answer.

Comment: Sorry I  can't find where you are trying to use your conditional style "Style1", try to set it to a textField or a cellContents and see what happens?

Comment: Please do not get me wrong, I'm really here to help you but the policy on SO is to not put answer if there is a duplicated question, check how in answer of duplicated he uses the style in the textField "<reportElement style="ZFieldStyle" ..."

Comment: The difference come is that in a normal detail report i can get the style sheet to work, but in a matrix you use measured fields. And i cannot get the measured field to read the style sheet at all

Comment: Create a [mcve], where you try to do this, so we can test it (can't find this in currently posted jrxml)

Comment: For info, I have test with a conditional expression on a crosstab value $V, applying the conditional style to a textField (in the crosstab) and I can't replicate your problem... If you have error please post error as well.

Comment: thanks peter - Would you mind putting a desc of your style sheet, just to change the color

Comment: I have done exactly as in duplicated question, <style name="test">
  <conditionalStyle>
   <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{NR_COLLI}>5]]></conditionExpression>
   <style forecolor="#FF3333"/>
  </conditionalStyle>
 </style>, where $V{NR_COLLI} is an Integer (measure in crosstab) and then I put "test"  as style to a textField (inside the crosstab)....

Comment: You probably have a different problem, consider to create a [mcve] otherwise I do not know how to answer...